# compile csharp project with Mono

Tags: c#, linux, windows, mono

How can I use mono mcs to compile a CSharp project with "Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00"?
It's a project with a bunch of directories, each of them containing `*.cs`, `*.csproj` and `*.csproj.vspscc` files.

As far as I know the only development platform for this project is Windows and nobody ever attempted to compile it in Linux, although the project, when compiled in Windows, succesfully runs in Linux under mono.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mono has its own version of MSBuild called [xbuild](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/xbuild/) which you can use to build the .sln or .csproj files.

If you need to use the Mono compiler directly you would need to look at the project files and create your own command line to pass to the compiler. It will be simpler to use xbuild.